# Polymorphism in Golang?

Tags: go

I am fairly new to Go and I have been doing OOP for a long time. Now, I understand that inheritance is done via composition but ... I'd like to send a specialization in a function expecting a generalization as such:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    ONE int
}

type B struct {
    A
    ANOTHER int
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    a := A{1}
    b := B{a, 2}

    fmt.Println(a.ONE)
    fmt.Println(b.ANOTHER)

    takeA(&b)
}

func takeA(a *A) {

    fmt.Println(a.ONE)
}
```

Sure, I can do `takeA(&b.A)` but it defeats the hierarchy I am trying to set up as some A fields/method could be shadowed in B.

Is there a way around this? Or should I create a dumb interface such as:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    ONE int
}

func (a A) getOne() int{
    return a.ONE
}

type B struct {
    A
    ANOTHER int
}

type HasOne interface {
    getOne() int
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    a := A{1}
    b := B{a, 2}

    fmt.Println(a.ONE)
    fmt.Println(b.ANOTHER)

    takeA(b)
}

func takeA(a HasOne) {

    fmt.Println(a.getOne())
}
```

Comment: Go is not object oriented. You would use interfaces as in your second piece of code depending on how you wanted to implement it and what you need it to do.

Comment: Go is not an object-oriented language, and does not support strict polymorphism. The only form of polymorphism supported by Go is interfaces.

Comment: @Adrian: I understand that. So, my interface would be the correct way to achieve my needs in Go ?

Comment: It's hard to say, because your question doesn't really say what you're trying to accomplish, just the way that you're trying to accomplish it (see [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). More than likely, if you're thinking in OOP terms, you need to rethink your design from the ground up in Go terms, as was my experience going from Java/C# to Go.

Comment: `"inheritance is done via composition"`, no that is not inheritance. Starting off by structuring your code as if there is inheritance is always going to lead you in the wrong direction.

Comment: As a side note, a method on a struct should always take a pointer to a struct, not a value e.g. `func (a *A) getOne() int{}` instead of `func (a A) getOne() int{}`. If you don't use a pointer, a copy is passed, so any changes will not be reflected in the variable you called it on.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear that may be a good rule of thumb for new developers who might get confused by pointer semantics, but it is absolutely not the universal truth that saying "should always" implies.

Comment: @Adrian true enough, but based on my own experience, I've not encountered any circumstance to make me even think twice about which to use. I suppose if you really did want to operate on a copy instead of the original, but that's all I can think of, but I've never had the need.

Comment: @JimB is absolutely right on all counts (as usual!). Inheritance isn't "done via composition"; [composition is done *instead of* inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no inheritance in Go. Composition doesn't give you dynamic dispatch (which is usually implied when 'polymorphism' and 'inheritance' are used in the same paragraph): the embedded method call always happens on the embedded field as a receiver, not on the container type it is embedded into.